# Using dojo's declare function: what is the first parameter?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I sometimes see two slightly different ways to when using `declare` in dojo:

way one is

```
define(["dojo/_base/declare"], function(declare){
  return declare(null, {
    constructor: function(){

    }
  });
```

which contrasts

```
define(["dojo/_base/declare"], function(declare){
  return declare("some/string/with/slashes/parameter",null, {
    constructor: function(){

    }
  });
```

I would like to know what the reason for the `"some/string/with/slashes/parameter"` in the second version is about?

Does a module/"dojo class" need to name itself, or is the nameing not always implied by its filename?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This first declaration will create an anonymous class ( availble withing its scope only ) so to access this last you you should make acces to it or its package in the dojoConfig global var ,

For the seconde declaration this last , is being created in the global scope ( app scope ) , so it can be instantiated or used using its declared class name `some.string.with.slashes.parameter` (recomanded to use dots insted of slash) that define generaly the name space conataing this class + class name.

Not that in the dojo [documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/declare/) :

> Named classes should only be created if they will be used with the
>   Dojo parser. All other classes should omit the className parameter.

this means using the second declaration only for widgets or class used withing `dojo/parser` like creating a custom declartion of Button (ovveride or extend ) ...